# how EMV cryptogram ARQC is culcalated by authorizer?

Tags: emv

Trying to verify  ARQC cryptograms on authorizer side

have tried some available texts , but see divergences on key sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ARQC is verified by an HSM( hardware security module ).
ARQC requires

- all CDOL elements which were used by the card while ARQC was
  computed.
- ATC
- IMK-AC

Download EMV Book 2 and read section 8.1.2 Application Cryptogram Algorithm and its annexes to have a good understanding.
Then you need to read the card's payment scheme's documentation for a dull understanding of the card you are working on.

Comment: Usually also AIP and Issuer Application Data apart from the ones you've mentioned